# Dynamic scheduling not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, resque-scheduler

Dynamic scheduling not working in rails, every time needs to execute
 
`rake resque:scheduler`
 
`rake resque:work`

**My working environment** 
`rails 3.2.13`
 
`resque-1.25.2`
 
`resque-scheduler-3.0.0`
 
`ruby 2.0.0p247`

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to lunch resque scheduler with the `DYNAMIC_SCHEDULE` env variable set to true:

`DYNAMIC_SCHEDULE=true rake resque:scheduler`